# Generating unique file name using UUID in golang

Tags: go, uuid

I need to generate an unique file name with UUID1.

My current python code is:

```
uuid.uuid1().hex[:16] // i need 16 chars file name
```

What could be the golang equivalent?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

There isn't a guid or uuid type in the standard library for Go but there are some other ways to do it, like using a third party package such as this; https://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/go-uuid/uuid or https://github.com/nu7hatch/gouuid

```
import "github.com/nu7hatch/gouuid"

id, err := uuid.NewV4()
```

This answer has another option as well which makes use of Unix command line utils; [Is there a method to generate a UUID with go language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15130321/is-there-a-method-to-generate-a-uuid-with-go-language) though it doesn't seem to perform very well.

Comment: code.google.com is about to be shutdown. The `go-uuid` package moved to https://github.com/pborman/uuid.

Answer (score 5):

I believe you have an impedance mismatch in your problem statement, and your Python code would not work as you expect it should.

As can be deduced by some answers at “*[Is there a method to generate a UUID with go language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15130321/is-there-a-method-to-generate-a-uuid-with-go-language)*”, as well as is clearly described in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_1_(date-time_and_MAC_address), ***UUIDs*** are very likely to be unique only when taken in full, not in parts, and are not necessarily random at all, especially with the Version 1 actually being rather predictable, as it's based on the date/time and MAC address of the host generating it.

As such, the best approach may be to use something similar to the code in one of the [answers to the prior mentioned question](//stackoverflow.com/a/25736155/1122270), to actually generate a random filename based on [`crypto/rand`](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/rand/) yourself to your own specification, and without the misuse of the libraries not necessarily intended to provide the required randomness for the task at hand.

https://play.golang.org/p/k2V-Mc5Y31e

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/rand"
    "fmt"
)

func random_filename_16_char() (s string, err error) {
    b := make([]byte, 8)
    _, err = rand.Read(b)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    s = fmt.Sprintf("%x", b)
    return
}

func main() {
    s, _ := random_filename_16_char()
    fmt.Println(s)
}
```